# Using bitwise comparation in logstash

Tags: logstash, bitwise-operators, logstash-configuration, logstash-file

How can I use if conditions to check for bitwise existence?
I have an Flag's enum (in c#) and I want to do different operations in logstash according to its value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

logstash does not directly support bitwise conditionals. You can use a ruby filter to convert the enum to a string

```
ruby { code => 'flag = event.get("Flags"); if flag { event.set("[@metadata][flags]", flag.to_i.to_s(2)) }' }
```

then pick it apart using grok to select each bit and then test each of them using conditionals. It may be easier to [do the whole thing](https://discuss.elastic.co/t/how-to-prevent-clobbering-in-translate-filter/280008/4?u=badger) in ruby.

Comment: That's a bit overhead for a simple bit comparition.. Thanks!